# Does thiserror ship an unstable feature so that it does not work with stable rust release?

Tags: rust, thiserror

I am working on [this repo](https://github.com/chunjiw/oxd). It builds with no problem on MacOS on a M2 Laptop; but when I try to build it on a Debian desktop, it shows this error:

```
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> /home/username/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/thiserror-1.0.37/src/lib.rs:238:34
    |
238 | #![cfg_attr(provide_any, feature(provide_any))]
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: could not compile `thiserror` due to previous error
```

So I tried to use nightly build on Debian `rustup default nightly`, then it builds with no errors.

I'm baffled because thiserror is a popular crate. Is it true that thiserror crate ships with an unstable feature even though it doesn't work with stable rust? Does that mean that most rust developers use the nightly version instead of the stable version?

But then why it works for me on a Mac? I'm pretty sure I have the stable version on the Mac.

There must be something I'm missing :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: But the repo you linked doesn't even depend on `thiserror`...

Comment: Note that the error line you show clearly has `#![cfg_attr(provide_any, ...)]` which means it's only active if you request the `provide_any` feature of `thiserror`. Otherwise, it works on stable.

Comment: @BlackBeans Which is weird to me, because looking at `thiserror`'s `Cargo.toml`, it doesn't even _have_ that feature yet (which makes sense as it's still unstable). Can you activate a feature that a crate officially doesn't have?

Comment: @isaactfa by reading the source code, it seems like the `provide_any` feature is enabled if the `thiserror_nightly_testing` feature, which can probably be passed with `--features ...` during testing. The question is how is this enabled in OP's code...

Comment: @BlackBeans Ah, I didn't even think to look in the tests... still weird, but oh well.

Comment: @isaactfa oh yeah I found in it in the [ci](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror/blob/b37dc365b62532249020b38d84447464ab902ab6/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L24).

Comment: @isaactfa I think some crates in `Cargo.toml` depend on `thiserror`.

Comment: So somehow the feature is enabled in Linux but not in Mac?

Comment: Just remove your `target` directory and rebuild all. This happened to me twice after `cargo update`-ing my dependencies on unrelated projects. It seems the `build.rs` output from thiserror isn't updated correctly.
Also see https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror/issues/192

Comment: @SirDarius Thank you! I didn't see this issue #192... I need to keep honing my search skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented above by @SirDarius, just remove the `target` directory and the crate rebuilds without issue.